# Missing "Select" option to select multiple files in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, files-app

Does anyone know why there is no `Select` option when tapping `3 dots` in `UIDocumentPickerViewController` like it is in a `Files app`? Even if multipleSelection is set to `true`.
I noticed that it appears on simulator, but not on the real device.

```
private lazy var _documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.image",
         "public.audio",
         "public.movie",
         "public.text",
         "public.item",
         "public.content",
         "public.source-code"],
        in: .import)

private final func performDocumentsMenuOpen() {
        present(self._documentPicker, animated: true) {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                self._documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by

- moving `allowsMultipleSelection = true` before presenting documentPicker
- changing animated to false in `present(self._documentPicker, animated: true)`